# Is it possible in Flutter to know which page of PDF the user is currently scroll to?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I need to make a mobile interface where user can download attached PDF (if it isn't downloaded yet) and open it on the screen. The requirement is, if the user close the PDF midway reading, for example, the user close the PDF when they scroll at page 7, then on subsequent opening the PDF, I have to instantly scroll the user to page 7, so they can start where they left.

I already have the answer for opening PDF at a specific initial page at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60411386). I haven't tried that solution at the moment.

But now all left is to detect at what page the user closes the PDF. I searched around, but can't seem to find even any discussion or question about it. Can somebody help?

Comment: What pdf reader package are you using? most of them have a `Controller` which you can use to see what page the user is on and set an initial page.

Comment: @aligator probably https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view according to the answer I have in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `pdfController.page` to get the current page:

```dart
class PDFPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialPage;
  final String filePath;

  const PDFPage({Key key, this.initialPage, this.filePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFPageState createState() => _PDFPageState();
}

class _PDFPageState extends State<PDFPage> {
  PdfController pdfController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pdfController = PdfController(
      document: PdfDocument.openFile(widget.filePath),
      initialPage: widget.initialPage ?? 1,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // save current page here
        await savePageForPDF(widget.filePath, pdfController.page);
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: PdfView(
          controller: pdfController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  savePageForPDF(String filePath, int page) {...}
  
}
```